# ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-4)

Tags: c++, stdvector

Trying to write some code, and erase() is giving me a runtime error. What's wrong with the way I used erase?

```
class Solution {
    public:
        vector<int> findDisappearedNumbers(vector<int>& nums) {
            int size = nums.size();
            vector<int> list; 
            for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
                list.push_back(i);
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int num = nums[i];
                list[num - 1] = 0;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if(list[i] == 0) {
                    list.erase(list.begin() + i);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    };
```

Here's the problem I am trying to solve

Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.

Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array.

Could you do it without extra space and in O(n) runtime? You may assume the returned list does not count as extra space.

Example:

Input:
[4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]

Output:
[5,6]

Comment: Could you provide more information on the task/exercise?

Comment: Are you taking into account iterator invalidation for `erase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the non solutions were marked 0, you can remove all 0's in the vector using `list.erase( remove (list.begin(), list.end(), 0), list.end() );`

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion, concentrate on this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(list[i] == 0) {
            list.erase(list.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

You are removing elements from `list` which changes the `size`. This will lead to accessing elements beyond your `list`.